# CSS class not being selected

Tags: html, css

I have made a div that when you rollover it, a second div should be displayed with content in it.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <img src="" width="80" height="80" style="background-color: #666666">
    <div class="hover">la</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    background-color:red;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position: relative;
} 

#nav .hover {
background: #f8f8f8; 
    height: auto; width: 800px;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%; 
    visibility:hidden;
    margin: -10px 0px 0px -400px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #afafaf;  
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px -2px #444;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

#nav:hover > #nav .hover {   <---
    visibility:visible;
}
```

My problem is the class isn't selected and won't display when rolled over (the class of which I am talking about is marked <---)

Whats supposed to happen: You roll over the grey square anda blue line pops up

What actually happens: You roll over it at nothing happens

Please advise.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cLuL/

Comment: Incorrect: `#nav:hover > #nav .hover` - change to `#nav:hover > .hover `

Comment: I would recommend not setting classname to hover. I think that confuses more then it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this and your fine

```
   #nav:hover > .hover {
        visibility:visible;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Nice simple fix and fast. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have this html...

```
<div id="nav">
    <img src="" width="80" height="80" style="background-color: #666666">
    <div class="hover">la</div>
</div>
```

and you have this in your css:

```
#nav:hover > #nav .hover
```

...when hover occurs on the `#nav-element`, it applies style to child of the `#nav`, but `#nav` within it, therefore your code does not work.

*It would work* with html like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav">
        <img src="" width="80" height="80" style="background-color: #666666">
        <div class="hover">la</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**but above is not valid html.**

With this css...

```
#nav:hover > .hover {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

...when hovering the `#nav` it makes the child of `#nav` that has class `.hover` visible.